# Create a user interface using Wx in which the image is loaded from it and the plot is drawn over it by using wxmplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, wxpython, ipython, wxwidgets

Using the following program I get an output of background image in panel1..
And the buttons in panel2.
1) I want the plot on the background image.
2) And the inputs are given from panel2.
How the plotting can be linked to background image?

import wx
    import numpy as np
    from wxmplot import PlotApp

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(1200,600))
        splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, -1)

        self.panel1 = wx.Panel(splitter, -1)
        panel2 = wx.Panel(splitter, -1)

        self.panel1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.LIGHT_GREY)
        panel2.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)

        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        usernameLbl = wx.StaticText(panel2, label="Enter Angle:")
        self.username = wx.TextCtrl(panel2)
        self.addWidgets(usernameLbl, self.username)

        disbtn = wx.Button(panel2, label='Submit', pos=(90,40))
        disbtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onClick)

        panel2.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)
        self.Show()  

        self.sld = wx.Slider(panel2, -1, 45, 0, 360, (60,100), (250, -1),
                              wx.SL_AUTOTICKS | wx.SL_HORIZONTAL | wx.SL_LABELS)
        btn1 = wx.Button(panel2, 8, 'Adjust',pos=(90,150))
        wx.EVT_BUTTON(self, 8, self.OnAdjust)
        btn2 = wx.Button(panel2, 9, 'Close',pos=(180,150))
        wx.EVT_BUTTON(self, 9, self.OnClose)


        #img = wx.EmptyImage(400,400)
        img = wx.Image('image path')

        self.bitmap = wx.Bitmap('image path')
        wx.EVT_PAINT(self, self.OnPaint)
        self.Centre()


        self.imageCtrl = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel1, wx.ID_ANY, 
                                        wx.BitmapFromImage(img))

        splitter.SplitVertically(self.panel1, panel2)

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.bitmap, 60,20)


    def OnAdjust(self, event):
        val = self.sld.GetValue()
        print int(val)
    def OnClose(self, event):
        self.Close()

    def addWidgets(self, lbl, txt):
        """"""
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(lbl, 1, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        sizer.Add(txt, 2, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.mainSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND)

    def onClick(self,event):
        #global app
        pai1 = (self.username.GetValue())
        self.username.Remove(0,len(pai1))
        pai=int(pai1)
        print pai
        th = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,500)
        p=(np.cos(2*th)*np.cos(3*th))
        x = (p * np.cos(th+np.radians(pai)))
        y = (p * np.sin(th+np.radians(pai)))
        app.plot(self.panel1,x, y, label='PLOT', marker='.')

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'splitterwindow.py')
        frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True


app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: That is more of a wxmplot or matplotlib question, you might want to update your tags.